# Loop through NSArray of objects that has no id's - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I have an NSArray that looks like the following

```
[{
   "Id":"456",
   "Type":"Dog",
   "Sound":"Bark",
},
{
   "Id":"789",
   "Type":"Cat",
   "Sound":"Meow",
}]
```

I tried the following

```
for (id key in array) { // Doesn't work
  NSLog(@"%@", key[@"Type"]);
}
```

and I tried

```
NSLog(@"%@", [array firstObject]); // Doesn't work
```

This doesn't work however because there is no id to access. I get an `NSInvalidArgumentException` for both. How would I successfully loop through the two objects that I have and print out the type?

Comment: Looks like your array variable is not NSArray subclass. Add breakepoint and inspect it.

Comment: Yeah, your code looks fine.  How is the array getting set?  And how do you know what the contents are?  Post that code and you'll be more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: If `[array firstObject]` gives you an `NSInvalidArgumentException`, then `array` is not an `NSArray`. Read the error message and see what it actually is.

Comment: Put REAL code. It seems you don't have the knowledge to hide too much info from us. You need to show the real code, how you get the data, and also show the real and full error message for the `NSInvalidArgumentException`. It has plenty of debugging info, but you are hiding them from us.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit confusing, because you say:

> ```
> I have an NSArray that looks like the following
>
> [{
>    "Id":"456",
>    "Type":"Dog",
>    "Sound":"Bark",
> },
> {
>    "Id":"789",
>    "Type":"Cat",
>    "Sound":"Meow",
> }]
> ```

but then, you also say:

> NSLog(@"%@", [array firstObject]); // Doesn't work

Of course, you don't indicate what "Doesn't work" means... Does it throw an error? Does it output nothing? Does it output something, but not what you expect?

However, if you **did** have an array that "looks like that", then let's see what it actually is...

We can think of a Dictionary as:

```
{ key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3, etc... }
```

and we can think of an Array as:

```
[object1, object2, object3, etc...]
```

So, assuming your example data *is* structured like that in a valid `NSArray`, that means you have an Array of 2 Dictionary objects. If you want to output them to the console, you can do:

```
// log the first object in the array
NSLog(@"%@", [array firstObject]);
```

and the output should be a Dictionary:

> ```
> {
>     Id = 456;
>     Sound = Bark;
>     Type = Dog;
> }
> ```

You can also do:

```
// for each element (each Dictionary) in array, output the dictionary
for (NSDictionary *d in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", d);
}
```

resulting in:

> ```
> ...[1234:4321] {
>     Id = 456;
>     Sound = Bark;
>     Type = Dog;
> }
>
> ...[1234:4321] {
>     Id = 789;
>     Sound = Meow;
>     Type = Cat;
> }
> ```

and, finally:

```
// for each element (each Dictionary) in array
for (NSDictionary *d in array) {
    // for each Key in each Dictionary
    for (NSString *key in [d allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@", key, d[key]);
    }
}
```

which will give you:

> ```
> ...[1234:4321] Sound - Bark
> ...[1234:4321] Id - 456
> ...[1234:4321] Type - Dog
> ...[1234:4321] Sound - Meow
> ...[1234:4321] Id - 789
> ...[1234:4321] Type - Cat
> ```

Note that dictionaries are *un-ordered, so don't count on stepping through the keys in the same order each time.

Hope that makes sense. Of course, you still need to find out why you think you have a NSArray when you don't.

Comment: Thanks, the error I get when I do these is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString firstObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000253e00'
", which leads me to assume that you are correct when saying that it isn't an NSArray. But why would I be able to create an NSArray that looks like this in the first place? If I had an NSDictionary that looked the same way would that also be incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean *"looks like this"*? How are you seeing "that"? How are you creating whatever object you are looking at? Where is it coming from?